# Is the building Spider-Man slings through at the end of Far From Home real?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, spider-man-far-from-home

At the end of *Far From Home* Spider-Man swings through New York to pick up MJ. He glides through a skyscraper that has a tree filled terrace halfway up.

Is this a real building in New York?

Comment: Cross-site answer: https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/107090/what-new-york-building-does-spider-man-glide-through-in-far-from-home

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No it is CGI, Julian Foddy at Industrial Light & Magic, the team behind the sequence, tells us that it is digitised in the interview below:

> Julian Foddy and his team at Industrial Light & Magic's London office were responsible for the visual effects behind that final Manhattan-based sequence, including the flythrough of what was formerly known as Avengers Tower. Though Foddy wasn't told what the tower was exactly, he was given instructions from Sony and Marvel Studios on sprucing it up quite a bit, even using some real-life references.
>
> "It was actually a direction from Marvel themselves, but they wanted this tall building to have replaced, what was it? The Avenger Tower, or Stark Tower," Foddy tells us. "In previous movies, we've established that Tony's sold the building and the new building has gone up in its place."
>
> "I don't know whether at any point in the future what that building is," the VFX guru admits. "That's maybe referenced again, or whether it's just a cool skyscraper but yeah, at least I think that there's a building in Singapore that has this internal garden atrium a little bit like that. This was an idea that — I don't know if you've seen the movie Skyscraper — but I think that has it. There's a similar thing there, and we basically used that for reference."
>
> <sub>[comicbook, Spider-Man: Far From Home VFX Supervisor Teases Future of Avengers Tower](https://comicbook.com/marvel/news/spider-man-far-from-home-who-bought-avengers-tower/)</sub>

Comment: Gotta be the Baxter Building eh.